# Pushing information to a dataframe while looping through a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looping through a dictionary from the Pytrends Google trends API and aiming to populate a dataframe.

I'm able to print within the loop - but when I try and pass the same printed value to a dataframe, only one result is returned and the loop doesn't execute - so I'm having to manually create and concatenate a lot of dataframes outside the loop.

The below prints all of the 'rising' search terms for all queries looped through:

```
dicti = {}
i = 0
for trending in groupkeywords:
    pytrend.build_payload(trending, timeframe = 'today 12-m', geo = 'GB')
    dicti[i] = pytrend.related_queries()
    print(dicti[i].get(values_list[i]).get('rising'))
    i+=1
```

However the following only prints one iteration of the dataframe from the loop:

```
dicti = {}
i = 0
for trending in groupkeywords:
    pytrend.build_payload(trending, timeframe = 'today 12-m', geo = 'GB')
    dicti[i] = pytrend.related_queries()
    df = dicti[i].get(values_list[i]).get('rising')
    i+=1

print(df)
```

Is there a way to populate the dataframe for all values returned from the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the data frame everytime, and most likely you need your data frame to be in the long format, so for example:

```
pytrends = TrendReq(hl='en-US', tz=360)
groupkeywords = ["Blockchain","Crypto"]

dicti = {}
list_df = []

for trending in groupkeywords:
    pytrends.build_payload([trending], timeframe = 'today 12-m', geo = 'GB')
    dicti[trending] = pytrends.related_queries()
    df = dicti[trending].get(trending).get('rising')
    df['keyword'] = trending
    list_df.append(df)
```

You get back one data frame for each keyword:

```
list_df[0].head()

    query   value   keyword
0   blockchain backer   111650  Blockchain
1   argo blockchain news    102650  Blockchain
2   argo blockchain shares  97850   Blockchain
3   bitcoin price usd   89450   Blockchain
4   argo blockchain share price chat    82950   Blockchain

list_df[1].head()

    query   value   keyword
0   bee crypto  90150   Crypto
1   defi crypto 89400   Crypto
2   nft crypto  81950   Crypto
3   polkadot crypto 74900   Crypto
4   uniswap 68850   Crypto
```

You can concatenate them like this:

```
pd.concat(list_df)
```

Comment: Thank you! I've made some changes based on the above and works to get the data in bulk as a list and then concatenate list items :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to increment dataframe index
...
df.loc[i] =...
i=i+1

You have to instantiate the dataframe before your loop.
df = pd.dataframe(columns=[name])